# flex-flow doesn't put my 3 elements in columns, elements stay in default rows?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

### I switched from display:grid; to display:flexbox; because of design options for my three columns.

I want my columns to look as the following:

- Desktop Viewport:
  3 columns next to each other.
- Tablet Viewport:
  2 columns on the 1st row and 1 on the 2nd row (in the center of the 2nd row) to resemble a Y shape.
- Mobile Viewport:
  All 3 columns go under each other in 3 rows.

Problem is:
flex-flow: column wrap won't put my elements in columns and stays in rows.

```css
.grid-container {
  display: flex;
  margin: 100px 100px;
  width: 400px;
  height: 800px;
  flex-flow: column wrap;
}

.grid-container .column {
  background-color: #9c1f0a;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px 0;
  font-size: 30px;
  border-radius: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-container">
  <div id="left" class="column">
    <span>COLUMN1</span>
  </div>
  <div id="center" class="column">
    <span>COLUMN2</span>
  </div>
  <div id="right" class="column">
    <span>COLUMN3</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: it is `display:flex`NOT `flexbox`;)

Comment: It is indeed :) my mistake.  Yet it still does not work?

Comment: Are you looking to display 3 columns with in a single row, then 

flex-flow: row wrap;

Comment: That is for the mobile viewport. But for the desktop I need flex-flow: column wrap;

Comment: it will also wrap into columns once content reached the 800px height you did set, as long as there is enough room, it doesn't wrap to another column ;)

Answer (score 0):

I have made some changes in your code.
First of all remove the `width` and `height` from the container. Also, remove the `flex-flow` property. Now add `flex-wrap: wrap`, because of this property it will wrap the items on the new line. Also add `justify-content: center` this will enable elements to centered aligned across the horizontal axis.

I have also added `flex: 0 0 200`, which means the item won't grow and shrink and will always have a width: 200px.

If you wish to change the width you can assign different flex property to each item, instead of 200px you can write different values, let's say this way:

```css
#left {
  flex: 0 0 100px;
}

#center {
  flex: 0 0 200px;
}

#right {
  flex: 0 0 300px;
}
```

I believe this is what you are looking for:

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  margin: 0 auto;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
}

.container .column {
  background-color: #9c1f0a;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px 0;
  font-size: 1rem;
  border-radius: 20px;
  flex: 0 0 200px
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div id="left" class="column">
    <span>COLUMN1</span>
  </div>
  <div id="center" class="column">
    <span>COLUMN2</span>
  </div>
  <div id="right" class="column">
    <span>COLUMN3</span>
  </div>
</div>
```